# Ribbon doesn't see property

Tags: java, spring, properties, netflix-eureka, netflix-ribbon

I'm using ribbon and eureka and I want add the following property:

```
my-service.ribbon.ServerListRefreshInterval
```

However, the default context doesn't see this property. I'm using ribbon as a loadBalancer. Currently I fixed it by using:

```
 ConfigurationManager.loadPropertiesFromResources("my-service.properties");
```

Is this the only way to fix this?

Example of my code:

```
@Component
public class ServiceClientFactory 
{
    @Inject
    public ServiceClientFactory(
    private String applicationName="firstApp";

    final SpanAccessor spanAccessor
            final LoadBalancerClient loadBalancer,
            ) throws IOException {

            loadBalancer.choose(applicationName);

    }
}
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
public class ServiceApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ServiceApplication()
                .configure(new SpringApplicationBuilder(ServiceApplication.class))
                .run(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it not working when you are giving this property in application.properties file? if not then could you please share your code?

Comment: @Gaurav, yes it's not working when I put this property in application.properties

Comment: Can you share your code? you can create a github repository and place your code there, as if I am trying this, it is working for me.

Comment: I have tried this without eureka service discovery and it is working in that case. see https://github.com/vickygupta0017/microservice-ribbon

Comment: @Gaurav I can't show code now, only tomorrow. And I don't user ribbon client I just use  ribbonLoadBalancer.

Comment: @Gaurav I added the example of code.

Comment: It is very difficult to give conclusion without seeing the actual code, but I have tried to consume a eureka enable service with the ribbon(load balancing), and it is successfully taking the serverListRefreshInterval from the application.properties file. see code at (https://github.com/vickygupta0017/microservice-ribbon).

Comment: @Gaurav Thank you